# How to put different color for the text in a TNewStaticText in inno setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have a  variable of TNewStaticText datatype and i want to set different colors for the text, For example
if the the variable  contains text like "Have a nice day"

"Have" should be displayed in red color
"a nice" should be displayed in blue color
"day" should be displayed in black color

Comment: As far as I know it is impossible for single string. In this case you should make 2 TNewStaticText strings and the you will be able to set different color for each one (e.g. `YourTNewStaticTextName.Font.Color:= clRed;`). Some time ago TLama created HTML version of text input for IS - but there was an issue with License text in this build of IS and I don't know if it was fixed eventually.

Comment: my answer was a direction where you can find the answer. its not nice to downvote that

Comment: @real_yggdrasil, I'm not a downvoter, but your answer is totally unrelated to this question. It shows how to create a custom form with two buttons. If the answer is the link you've posted, it is also a wrong way. You should always put the essential parts of the linked stuff into the post itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Font color you can change with the `Font.Color` property, but it's for the whole control's text. For your aim you need to create three controls. Here is an example:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard;
var
  TopPos: Integer;
  LeftPos: Integer;
  StaticText: TNewStaticText;
begin
  TopPos := WizardForm.NextButton.Top;
  LeftPos := 8;

  StaticText := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  StaticText.Parent := WizardForm;
  StaticText.Left := LeftPos;
  StaticText.Top := TopPos;
  StaticText.Font.Color := clRed;
  StaticText.Caption := 'Have ';

  LeftPos := StaticText.Left + StaticText.Width;

  StaticText := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  StaticText.Parent := WizardForm;
  StaticText.Left := LeftPos;
  StaticText.Top := TopPos;
  StaticText.Font.Color := clBlue;
  StaticText.Caption := 'a nice ';

  LeftPos := StaticText.Left + StaticText.Width;

  StaticText := TNewStaticText.Create(WizardForm);
  StaticText.Parent := WizardForm;
  StaticText.Left := LeftPos;
  StaticText.Top := TopPos;
  StaticText.Font.Color := clBlack;
  StaticText.Caption := 'day!';
end;
```

Or, to make your code more flexible, you can wrap this process to a function like follows:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Code]
type
  TColorArray = array of TColor;

procedure CreateColoredText(const ATexts: TArrayOfString; const AColors: TColorArray;
  AParent: TWinControl; ALeft, ATop: Integer);
var
  I: Integer;
  LeftPos: Integer;
begin
  if GetArrayLength(ATexts) <> GetArrayLength(AColors) then
    RaiseException('Inconsistent array parameters.');

  LeftPos := ALeft;
  for I := 0 to GetArrayLength(ATexts) - 1 do
  begin
    with TNewStaticText.Create(AParent) do
    begin
      Parent := AParent;
      Left := LeftPos;
      Top := ATop;
      Font.Color := AColors[I];
      Caption := ATexts[I];
      LeftPos := Left + Width;
    end;
  end;
end;

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  CreateColoredText(['Have ', 'a nice ', 'day!'], [clRed, clBlue, clBlack],
    WizardForm, 8, WizardForm.NextButton.Top);
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try something like this:

```
procedure FormButtonOnClick(Sender: TObject); 
var 
  Form: TSetupForm; 
  OKButton, CancelButton: TNewButton; 
begin 
  Form := CreateCustomForm(); 
  try 
    Form.ClientWidth := ScaleX(256); 
    Form.ClientHeight := ScaleY(256); 
    Form.Caption := 'TSetupForm'; 
    Form.CenterInsideControl(WizardForm, False); 

    OKButton := TNewButton.Create(Form); 
    OKButton.Parent := Form; 
    OKButton.Width := ScaleX(75); 
    OKButton.Height := ScaleY(23); 
    OKButton.Left := Form.ClientWidth - ScaleX(75 + 6 + 75 + 10); 
    OKButton.Top := Form.ClientHeight - ScaleY(23 + 10); 
    OKButton.Caption := 'OK'; 
    OKButton.ModalResult := mrOk; 

    CancelButton := TNewButton.Create(Form); 
    CancelButton.Parent := Form; 
    CancelButton.Width := ScaleX(75); 
    CancelButton.Height := ScaleY(23); 
    CancelButton.Left := Form.ClientWidth - ScaleX(75 + 10); 
    CancelButton.Top := Form.ClientHeight - ScaleY(23 + 10); 
    CancelButton.Caption := 'Cancel'; 
    CancelButton.ModalResult := mrCancel; 
    CancelButton.Cancel := True; 

    Form.ActiveControl := OKButton; 

    if Form.ShowModal() = mrOk then 
      MsgBox('You clicked OK.', mbInformation, MB_OK); 
  finally 
    Form.Free(); 
  end; 
end;
```

This example is copied from .htm">http://read.pudn.com/downloads115/sourcecode/windows/system/488914/Examples/CodeClasses.iss_.htm

Comment: I believe it's not the right answer to this question. Please review.

Comment: Seeing as my flag as "not an answer" was disputed, this doesn't actually ansswer the question of how to change the control colours or have multiple colours.